# CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer return buff size adjustable?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

what I do in the moment:

I have a Audio unit running with a callback to play audio from the iPod Lib.
In the callback I get the number of required samples for the playxback buffer(s) with `inNumberFrames`

```
static OSStatus playbackMP3Callback(void *inRefCon,
                                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                AudioBufferList *ioData) {
   BeepTrackController *remoteIOplayer = (__bridge BeepTrackController *)inRefCon;

   for (int i = 0 ; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++){
      AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i];
      if (remoteIOplayer->_isMP3Running == YES) {
        SInt16 peak = [remoteIOplayer getMP3Samples:buffer.mData nrOfAudioFrames:inNumberFrames];
      }else
        memset(buffer.mData,0,ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
  }
return noErr;
```

}

For iPod Lib Reading I use an AssetReader with CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer wich delivers a number of samples which is DIFFERENT to the requried number of samples from the audio callback buffer(s). Her just the important code lines:

```
 -(SInt16) getMP3Samples:(SInt16*)address nrOfAudioFrames:(NSInteger)nrOfFrames
 ... Loop ....
 CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
                                                      _mp3Control.nextbuffer,
                                                       NULL,
                                                       &audioBufferList,
                                                       sizeof(audioBufferList),
                                                       NULL,
                                                       NULL,
                                                       kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
                                                       &_mp3Control.blockBuffer
                                                      );
  ... SNIP ....
       for (int bufferCount=currentBuffer; bufferCount < audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; bufferCount++) {
           SInt16* samples = (SInt16 *)audioBufferList.mBuffers[bufferCount].mData;
           for (int i=currentSampleCount; i < audioBufferList.mBuffers[bufferCount].mDataByteSize/2 ; i++) {
              currentSample = samples[i];
              address [_mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount++] = currentSample;
              // End of Buffer reached?
              if (_mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount >nrOfFrames*2) {
                 _mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount = 0;
                 currentBuffer = bufferCount;
                 currentSampleCount = i;
                 return currentSample;
           }
        }
     }
```

So what I would like to have is that CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer returns exactly the amount of samples I need for my callback buffer in the AUnit callback. Since the structures are equal I suspect here must be a method to synchronize this.
I have achived audio playing but with ugly static pointers to different sized buffers and I want it more elegant and therefore robust.

Now I was reading the doco of the CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer function and we all know that except the header file there isnt a lot of documentation here.

Any hints? My tries did all fail in noise or crashes ... I know it must be possible ;-)

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the OS will return the audio buffer sizes you request or need. It may even change the sizes at run-time.  Thus, one should just make the app's intermediate buffering code clean and robust.  A lock free circular FIFO is one common solution.

Comment: Hi, I thought about a circular buffer but for filling that buffer I need some kind of event time which loads data into the buffer so the audio callback never runs dry of audio samples. I just wanted to avoid another asynchronous task to do but maybe thats the path to go ...